# Have a released version on 3 different branches

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 3 branches , test ,dev and master currently we only have a release version on master, what I want is to have a release version on each of the branches using maven and GitLab pipeline , so to better explain I want to have  3 versions without the -snapshot tag and without resulting in conflicts in versioning between the branches

Comment: What is your aim with this approach? What are these versions for?

Comment: Technically you can create a separate version for each branch like Master `1.X`, test `2.x` and dev `3.X` but I don't think it's a good idea. The question  Why would you like to make releases of each branches because based on the name I suppose only master should create a release... ?